# How to know when a fragment view is ready out of it

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have fragment which includes a viewpager which includes many fragments. I am calling methods of fragments which are in viewpager from outer fragment. I can do this without any problem but I am facing an issue, when I go to another fragment from fragments which are in viewpager and then I come back, I cannot use that method because method-calling object viewed as null.

Problem phases in order

[layout structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2zwO.png)

1- In outer fragment, a method of one of viewpager's fragment is called without anyproblem.

2- Click on anyitem in recycler view in fragments which are settled in viewpager.

3- It directs user to another fragment.

4- Go back via popbackstackimmediate().

5- First phase causes problem with null pointer exception.

This is the method implemented in outer fragment.

```
private void setPagination() {
    nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            if (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                if ((scrollY >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                        scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    if (currentPage.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
                        AFragment.loadMore();
                    else if (currentPage.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
                        BFragment.loadMore();
                    else if (currentPage.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
                        CFragment.loadMore();
                    else if (currentPage.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
                        DFragment.loadMore();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

LoadMore() method

```
public void loadMore() {
        if (list_a.size() % 4 == 0) {
            ManagerAll.getInstance().fetchA(id_number, page).enqueue(new Callback<List<A>>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<A>> call, Response<List<A>> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        int before_update = list_a.size();
                        list_a.addAll(response.body());
                        int after_update = list_a.size();
                        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(before_update, after_update);
                        page++;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<List<A>> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
}
```

I cannot access list_a here because it throws null pointer exception. I guess it is not initialized yet after I come back from another fragment.

Comment: Can you tell what methods do you need to call in fragments in ViewPager? And how do you go to another fragment from fragment in ViewPager (do you replace or add fragments, which fragmentManager do you use)?

Comment: I am calling a method that is loading more in recycler view. I detect bottom in outer fragment because I use nestedscrolling so I cannot detect it inside viewpager fragments

Comment: And how do you find your current fragment in ViewPager? Where do exactly you get NullPointerException?

Comment: I am listening bottom hit action in outerfragment and when it hits bottom it calls method of viewpager's fragment. It is okay in the first place but after coming from another fragment with popbackstackimmediate it throws null pointer

Comment: Can you please edit your post and provide some code? The structure of your app is complicated and it will be easier to understand and help you.

Comment: updated the post